# How can I configure uTorrent so that it doesn't stop seeding after the download of a torrent is completed?

Tags: torrents

By default on Android, μTorrent stops seeding after the download of a torrent is completed. How can I configure μTorrent so that it doesn't stop seeding after the download of a torrent is completed?

I don't want to have to manually unpause each torrent after the download is completed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is currently not possible to configure uTorrent so that it doesn't stop seeding after the download of a torrent is completed. However, Reddit user [-Krotik-](https://www.reddit.com/user/-Krotik-) [pointed](https://redd.it/18y1f8m) me to [LibreTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proninyaroslav.libretorrent&hl=en_US&gl=US), which does keep seeding after the download of a torrent is completed. Also, it has no ads and is opensource.